# How create .gdbinit in home directory (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, command-line, home-directory

l
Hello everybody,I need to create a .gdbinit file to use the command "go" on gdb.
Our prof told us to create it in home directory and it was simple.
On Linux all I needed was to being root.
Now with Mac I can't create the file even if I am root.
From command line if I type " touch .gdbinit " or if I create the file in a different directory and try to move it in home the result is always "Operation not supported".
Now I am very confused because I thought to be a god as root.
Maybe this is true on Linux,Mac is different.
However someone know how to create a .gdbinit file in home?
I work on Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why this shouldn't work:

```
cd
touch .gdbinit
```

Now check it exists:

```
ls -la .gdbinit
```

Comment: I have a screenshot of my terminal and I can ensure you that if I type : " cd home/ " then "touch .gdbinit" it says this " touch: .gdbinit: Operation not supported " and I'm root.

Comment: Ok, please run `type touch` and click `edit` under your question and paste the result. Then also run `cd; ls -la` and paste the result of that too.

Comment: touch is /usr/bin/touch. For cd; ls -la there are too many characters.Do u need of the hidden directories or the other?

Comment: Why do you type `cd home/` anyway? I suggested you type `cd` and `cd home/` is very different from `cd /home` or `cd $HOME`.

Comment: I type cd /home

Comment: How about typing `cd`, as I suggested.

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake,I didn't understand. However with cd and cd home/ : No such file or directory, don't hate me please :')